# MPMoviePlayerViewController continue play different video

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have 3 different video: video1,video2,video3

I want when video1 play end then continue play video2 then continue play video3 then finish

Here's my current code:

```
moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:video1];
[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

I think maybe i should use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
```

But when video1 play finish, navigationController dissmiss

How should I fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AVQueuePlayer` for queuing the videos.

Comment: I've try your suggestion, It's OK, but MovieControlBar disappear, is there any solutions to show it?